# Change only zeros to integers in list of floats

Tags: python, list, types, int

I have this output from my code

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0],
```

but I need to make it be like this -

```
[0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0]
```

Any tips on how to change the zeros to integers?

Comment: But why though?

Comment: You only want to change the zeroes, or all integerish floats?

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far and explain in detail what's not working. Best done by describing the expected and the actual behaviour. If your code throws an exception please include the full error trace.

Comment: yes, only 0 as an int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change all zeros to integers, a simple list comprehension will do.

```
>>> lst = [0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0]
>>> [x or 0 for x in lst]
[0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0]
```

If and only if `x == 0` then the expression will be evaluated to `0`.

This is assuming no other falsy values like empty strings or lists are in `lst`.

Comment: `x or int(x)` is actually `x or 0`

Comment: @bereal rather than golfing, better to be explicit IMO, there could other falsy values in the list; `[int(x) if x == 0 else x for x in lst]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I think we can assume the list is homogeneous. If you want to go into special cases, we'd also have to consider objects that evaluate equal to `0.0` but are not the float `0.0.` ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a weird request, but you can just do it on a case by case basis, turning all zeros into `int`s:

```
>>> output = [0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0]
>>> [int(x) if not x else x for x in output]
[0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0]
```

That list comprehension is the same as

```
new_list=[]
for x in output:
    if x == 0:
        new_list.append(int(x))
    else:
        new_list.append(x)
```

The `for`-loop form is easier for making more complicated replacement rules if you need to tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by **list comprehension** :

Example :

If i want all the numbers that are **less than 3** to be **integers** and **rest float** , then i would have done like this.

```
myList = [1.1 , 2.7 , 7.8 ,8 ,8.9 ,3.2]
myList = [ int(i) if i < 3 else i for i in myList ]
print(myList)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 7.8, 8, 8.9, 3.2]
```

Your required code is :

```
 myList = [0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0]
 myList = [int(i) if i == 0 else i for i in myList]
 print(myList)
```